# Exception when connecting to database on client machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, deployment, localdb

I have created a WPF application which used entity framework and SQL server 2012 for database. It runs fine on my machine. But when I ran this on client machine I received exception. This happens when I am trying to add a record in database.

Exception: The underlying provider failed on Open
Inner Exception: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, ........

Connection string:

```
<connectionStrings><add name="SchoolModelContext" 
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/SchoolModel.csdl|res://*/SchoolModel.ssdl|res://*/SchoolModel.msl;
    provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
    initial catalog=&quot;SCHOOLDB.MDF&quot;
    integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
    App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Is SQL Server installed on your client machine?

Comment: Yes, I have installed SQLLocalDB on client machine,

Answer (score 0):

The error message ... it gives hints that are sometimes rabbit-trails.  Basically the error is saying "I can't connect to sql Server, there is something wrong".

But.. you say you "installed SqlLocalDB" on the client.

Did you "wire up" the new database (SCHOOLDB)?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212961.aspx

A. Creating an Instance of LocalDB

The following example creates an instance of SQL Server Express LocalDB named SCHOOLDB using the SQL Server 2012 binaries and starts the instance.

```
SqlLocalDB.exe create "SCHOOLDB" 11.0 -s
```

Aka, did you run something like that?

(Other info from the MSDN article that may not be relevant to this question)

B. Working with a Shared Instance of LocalDB

Open a command prompt using Administrator privileges.

```
SqlLocalDB.exe create "SCHOOLDB"
SqlLocalDB.exe share "SCHOOLDB" "SchoolSharedLocalDB"
SqlLocalDB.exe start "SCHOOLDB"
SqlLocalDB.exe info "SCHOOLDB"
REM The previous statement outputs the Instance pipe name for the next step
sqlcmd –S np:\\.\pipe\SCHOOLDB#<use your pipe name>\tsql\query
CREATE LOGIN NewLogin WITH PASSWORD = 'Passw0rd!!@52'; 
GO
CREATE USER NewLogin;
GO
EXIT
```

Execute the following code to connect to the shared instance of LocalDB using the NewLogin login.

```
sqlcmd –S (localdb)\.\SchoolSharedLocalDB -U NewLogin -P Passw0rd!!@52
```

EDIT ::: (only read above this line for a general understanding...see below on steps I actually did)

Ok, the above is a little confusing because its hard to know if you're dealing with the ~instance or the database.

Let's try this:

```
SqlLocalDB.exe create "MySuperCoolLocalExpressInstance"
SqlLocalDB.exe share "MySuperCoolLocalExpressInstance" "MySuperCoolLocalExpressInstanceSHARED"
SqlLocalDB.exe start "MySuperCoolLocalExpressInstance"
SqlLocalDB.exe info "MySuperCoolLocalExpressInstance"
```

NOW, very important, get YOUR very unique "named pipe" value.

```
np:\\.\pipe\LocalDB#<use your pipe name>\tsql\query
```

Copy your SchoolDB.mdf and SchoolDB.ldf to :

```
c:\MyCoolLocalDatabaseFiles\
```

Now set your connection string to this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SchoolModelContext"
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/SchoolModel.csdl|res://*/SchoolModel.ssdl|res://*/SchoolModel.msl;
    provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#MYUNIQUEPIPENAME\tsql\query;attachdbfilename=C:\MyCoolLocalDatabaseFiles\SchoolDB.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

But substitute "MYUNIQUEPIPENAME" for your value.

The key is "attachdbfilename".  This is how to "on the fly" attach a database.

You have some alternates for using the named pipe syntax.  See:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012

*"User Instance on local SQL Server Express"*

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Do I need to copy mdf file to client? Or client need to create mdf file itself?

Comment: Ok...now I'm agreeing with you this isn't trivial.  I can connect to my "instance" through management studio, but if I try to add a database (through SSMS), it craps out.  I'm gonna play with it a little.  If you found an answer, please post.